# Permission Denied to edit/load bash file but username is not under root

Tags: mysql, bash, terminal

I'm following a sql tutorial which requires me to use the terminal, and the commands posted is as follows:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_profile
```

I'm getting an error: `permission denied: /Users/username/.bash_profile`

On checking who owns the bash file because one of the previous answers on here suggested that the error might be because of the root being the owner and not the username, I can see that I still own it. Why am I getting the permission denied error?

```
ls -la ~ | grep bash
-rw-r--r--@   1 username  staff     96 21 Mar 07:47 .bash_profile
```

Comment: The error is "/Users/username/.bash_profile"? Is that an error? What's your operating system? Whatever you're trying to do, I've never had the need to install MySQL manually, there's always a package manager available.

Comment: Mac? https://medium.com/enekochan/plus-and-at-symbols-listing-file-permissions-in-mac-os-x-ee541b131032

Comment: ~/.bash_profile isn't a regular script, and shouldn't be executable. Which is to say, you *should* get a permissions error if you try to run it the way you did. Permissions are not the problem and don't need to be fixed, the problem is that you need to use the `source` or `.` command to run it in the current shell: `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm using a mac, and apologies, I'm getting a permission denied message. I've edited the original post to include it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXV3zeQKqGY&t=4171s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org and wanted to follow the steps at 1:09:01

Comment: https://hathaway.cc/2008/06/how-to-edit-your-path-environment-variables-on-mac/ - Assuming this is really needed and Apple does not provide a visual tool to edit PATH (I'm not a Mac user).

Comment: @Nikhat Pay close attention to the command he types in that tutorial. He uses the `.` ("dot") command, not just the filename. The `.` is vital.